# How do you loop through a list to a variable and print the value outside of the loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to loop through a list and make a variable that contains the list + some other info to be able to use it outside the for loop, however when I print my variable outside the loop I only get the last item in the list. I want to see all of them in the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = ['apple', 'orange', 'peanut']
for item in a:
    mylist = '*' + item
    print item

print "------out of loop ----------"
print mylist
```

The output is:

```
apple
orange
peanut
------out of loop ----------
*peanut
```

Comment: Are you expecting `'*' + item` to be some sort of list operation? That's not something I'm familiar with in python. Perhaps you mean to `.append(item)` to the list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare mylist outside of the loop. also you need to use '+=' (append) to keep adding onto mylist

```
a = ['apple', 'orange', 'peanut']
mylist = ''
for item in a:
    mylist += '*' + item
    print(item)

print("------out of loop ----------")
print(mylist)
```

this output should be :

```
apple
orange
peanut
------out of loop ----------
*apple*orange*peanut
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I'm new to programming and was having a hard time searching for an answer

Answer (score 0):

With `mylist = '*' + item`you always overwrite the old value of `mylist`

If you want to keep it, you should do something like `mylist = mylist + '*' + item` , depending on what you want to display

Or a different solution would be `mylist += '*' + item`